# How did the Unsullied find out that Jon did this?

Tags: game-of-thrones

In the *Game of Thrones* finale, when Jon

> killed Daenerys,

nobody was there to see it. Even the body was nowhere to be found because Drogon took it.

How did Grey Worm and the Unsullied learn that

> Daenerys was no longer alive

and Jon was behind this?

Comment: It occurred to me that he must have admitted to it

Comment: Two went in, one came out.

Comment: @Valorum Wow. What a dumb person in "Game of Thrones". He could have ruled the entire Westeros, but he "didn't want it". Now, he is doing a job which has no purpose.

Comment: There was blood all over the floor (and his hands) and she was missing. That all seems fairly confirmatory that *something violent* took place.

Comment: @Möoz Except the roof wasn't there and Drogon was also missing. Daenerys could have simply gone for a ride. Jon could simply make a story and get out of the city.

Comment: Sure. If he was a filthy liar willing to lie his way onto the throne and hopefully no-one finds her body with his knife in her chest

Comment: @Möoz - Do 'Thunderdome' rules apply in Game of Thrones?

Comment: "There was blood all over the floor (and his hands) and she was missing. That all seems fairly confirmatory that something violent took place." - [Drogon squished Daenerys and flew away](https://i.imgur.com/mGjVXmi.jpg)

Comment: @Aegon - Again, reliant on him lying his arse off

Comment: It seems he _is_ Ned Stark's bastard after all.

Comment: Blood is on the dance floor. Blood is on the knife. Grey Worm 's got your number. Grey Worm says it's right.

Answer (score 40):

Jon most certainly told them what happened if they hadn't worked it out themselves but I think it's pretty self explanatory. Jon is, like Ned, *"an honourable fool"* and so would think it is the right thing to tell people, he doesn't lie. Dany even chastises him for something similar in Season 7 Episode 7, "The Dragon and the Wolf", for not lying to Cersei to get her help. He was brought up not to weasel out of things like this but that aside he is in a fragile enough state that I doubt he'd have been able to lie even if he wanted to.

Jon goes into the Throne Room with Longclaw and a dagger where only him and Dany are in there. A while later Drogon gets really angry, melts the Iron Throne and the back wall of the Throne Room. This would undoubtedly attract Unsullied attention who would rush in to see if their queen is in danger.

They'd come in seeing Drogon flying off and might be able to see Dany's body in his claws. If not they see Jon upset, covered in blood and missing his dagger. They then see a blood patch on the floor near where Jon was standing and most importantly can't see Dany.

It's not much of a stretch to work out from there that Jon did it. There was no one else around who could have done it.

Comment: A bit out of character for him to kill someone unarmed?

Comment: Out of character, yes, and that is why it made him feel like shit

Comment: @Seamusthedog Not at all. In the first episode, Jon is shown to agree with Ned's decision to execute a man for failing his duty and betraying an oath. He was unarmed and had no chance to resist-- he was a prisoner. And Jon agrees with Ned that the one to pass the sentence should swing the sword. He does the same with the traitors of the Night's Watch. Once Jon decides that Dany needs to be removed, and that killing her is the only way to do that, it's basically the same decision.

Comment: I thought Jon felt so bad because she was his 'queen' and, incest aside, he loved her?

Comment: @Seamusthedog re: killing someone unarmed... that would apply to combat; Killing Danerys was an execution. As I saw it, Jon was in love with Dany (incest apparently no big deal in the "Thrones" world), but he also understood that she must die, which required someone to take her life, which was a task he alone must complete - he alone had both the opportunity and moral authority.